# Beat the 3 available dungeons. What now?

Tags: going-under

In Going Under, I beat the 3 main dungeons, but now I'm confused as what to do next.

There is the coworking space that feels like just an endless dungeon, and there is no direction to go anywhere else.

But I guess I didn't hit the end because I haven't seen credits.

So after beating the 3 dungeons, what next?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nope, Co-Working Space is the way to go. Just keep going.

Comment: Okay. Really felt like it was an end bonus dungeon because it just reuses things from all the others and doesnt seem to have a big space in the story (NPCs dont really mention it)

Comment: @Fredy31 - Well, IIRC, the NPCs don't really hint on where to go much. Did you talk to Ray? I've beat everything except Work From Home, so I don't remember if he says anything.

Comment: Well, usually they try to talk about the current dungeon you are going through, not always tho. But after 2-3 runs of the coworking space I didn't get anybody talking about it. Maybe just bad luck.